# Problemas pra rodar Widfly 14

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc

Estou fazendo um curso onde crio um cadastro de clientes, mas no momento em que eu vou rodar o server Widfly 14, tenho o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro ao rodar server Widfly 14]

Conseguem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Já clicou no botão 'Details'?

Comment: Pedro, quando clico no botão 'Details' ele só me traz a mensagem "The home directory for "Widfly 14" cannot be empty.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei aqui parece que você tem que setar em algum lugar a variável `appserver_home`, mas eu não faço ideia onde isso possa ser configurado. Você sabe?

Comment: Bom, pode ser que precise ser setada nas variáveis de ambiente, vou fazer o teste.

Comment: Não deu certo não, continuo com o mesmo erro.